# createMenuBar Parameter Handler

Tags: google-apps-script

What steps will reproduce the problem?

1. Create a MenuBar object (createMenuBar)
2. Create a Server Handler point to menuHandler function (createServerHandler)
3. Add an item to MenuBar object with the parameters: Name and Handler object;

What is the expected output? What do you see instead?
At the handler function is expected that the parameter return the name of source object that was clicked. Now I see a null value.

On which browser & OS?
Chrome 19.0.1084.56 m
Windows 7 SP1 x64

Please provide any additional information below.

```
function buildMenu() {
    var app = UiApp.createApplication();

    var myRootMenu = app.createMenuBar(false);
    var txtTest = app.createTextBox().setText("test").setId("txtTest");
    var myHandler = app.createServerHandler("menuHandler").addCallbackElement(txtTest);

    myRootMenu.addItem("File", myHandler );

    app.add(myRootMenu);

    return app;

}

function menuHandler(e) {
    Logger.log(e);
}
```

---

The logging output is:
{parameter=null}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First : this is not an issue tracker, please post what you think are issues [where it should be](http://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/list)

Second : if you don't add any callBackElement to a serverhandler it cannot return any value. Please read the [docs](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guide_user_interfaces?hl=fr-FR#ViewUIElements) carefully.

Edit : following your comment :

the value returned by the CallBackElement is linked to its **name**, so your code should be like this :

```
app.createTextBox().setName('test').setText("test").setId("txtTest");
```

Here is a working example :

```
function buildMenu() {
    var app = UiApp.createApplication();
    var myRootMenu = app.createMenuBar(false);
    var txtTest = app.createTextBox().setText("Got it !").setName('test');
    var myHandler = app.createServerHandler("menuHandler").addCallbackElement(txtTest);
    myRootMenu.addItem("File", myHandler );
    app.add(myRootMenu);
  var doc = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  doc.show(app);
}
function menuHandler(e) {
    Logger.log(e);
}
```

Comment: Hi, Serge.
Following your recommendations, I added a callBack Element and continuing does not returning any value. (I edited original post with my code).